# Solve equation containing conditions (If expressions)

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the underneath equation. If I try Solve[AAA,dc], then I get no solution. Can anybody explain this?

```
AAA = {80000 If[0.1 (0.00005 - dc) + dc <= -0.00175, -35, 
      If[-0.00175 <= 0.1 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 0, 20000. (0.1 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
       If[0 < 0.1 (0.00005 - dc) + dc <= 0.00015, 20000. (0.1 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
        If[0.00015 <= 0.1 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 0.00115, 
         3.15 - 1000. (0.1 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
         If[0.00115 <= 0.1 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 1/4, 
          2.00462 - 4.01849 (0.1 (0.00005 - dc) + dc)]]]]] + 
    80000 If[0.3 (0.00005 - dc) + dc <= -0.00175, -35, 
      If[-0.00175 <= 0.3 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 0, 20000. (0.3 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
       If[0 < 0.3 (0.00005 - dc) + dc <= 0.00015, 20000. (0.3 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
        If[0.00015 <= 0.3 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 0.00115, 
         3.15 - 1000. (0.3 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
         If[0.00115 <= 0.3 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 1/4, 
          2.00462 - 4.01849 (0.3 (0.00005 - dc) + dc)]]]]] + 
    80000 If[0.5 (0.00005 - dc) + dc <= -0.00175, -35, 
      If[-0.00175 <= 0.5 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 0, 20000. (0.5 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
       If[0 < 0.5 (0.00005 - dc) + dc <= 0.00015, 20000. (0.5 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
        If[0.00015 <= 0.5 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 0.00115, 
         3.15 - 1000. (0.5 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
         If[0.00115 <= 0.5 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 1/4, 
          2.00462 - 4.01849 (0.5 (0.00005 - dc) + dc)]]]]] + 
    80000 If[0.7 (0.00005 - dc) + dc <= -0.00175, -35, 
      If[-0.00175 <= 0.7 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 0, 20000. (0.7 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
       If[0 < 0.7 (0.00005 - dc) + dc <= 0.00015, 20000. (0.7 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
        If[0.00015 <= 0.7 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 0.00115, 
         3.15 - 1000. (0.7 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
         If[0.00115 <= 0.7 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 1/4, 
          2.00462 - 4.01849 (0.7 (0.00005 - dc) + dc)]]]]] + 
    80000 If[0.9 (0.00005 - dc) + dc <= -0.00175, -35, 
      If[-0.00175 <= 0.9 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 0, 20000. (0.9 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
       If[0 < 0.9 (0.00005 - dc) + dc <= 0.00015, 20000. (0.9 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
        If[0.00015 <= 0.9 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 0.00115, 
         3.15 - 1000. (0.9 (0.00005 - dc) + dc), 
         If[0.00115 <= 0.9 (0.00005 - dc) + dc < 1/4, 
          2.00462 - 4.01849 (0.9 (0.00005 - dc) + dc)]]]]]} == 0
```

Comment: Boy that's one hairball of an expression.  I wouldn't be surprised if `Solve` doesn't help much anyway, but I believe that `If` should be expressed as `Boole` or `Piecewise`.  Also, you may have better luck `Rationalize`ing your numbers.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Reduce`：

```
Reduce[AAA // Rationalize, dc]
```

> dc == -(1/20000) || dc >= 49991/20000

`Rationalize` isn't necessary, without it a warning will be generated, it doesn't hurt much though.

Another approach, as sebhofer suggested in the comment below, is to use `Simplify` together with `PiecewiseExpand` or `LogicalExpand`, it works probably because generally conditionals written with `Piecewise`, or `And` and `Or` is more robust in *Mathematica*.

It's a pity that this solution isn't so perfect in version 8:

```
AAA // PiecewiseExpand // Simplify
```

> **Version 9:**  dc == -0.00005 || dc >= 2.49955
>
> **Version 8:**  (0.00005 + dc == 0 && 160000. + 3.2*10^9 dc == 0) || dc >= 2.49955

```
AAA // LogicalExpand // Simplify
```

> **Version 9:**  dc == -0.00005 || dc >= 2.49955
>
> **Version 8:**  (0.00005 + dc == 0 && 160000. + 3.2*10^9 dc == 0) || dc >= 2.49955

Comment: Nice, it's quite amazing that this works. Just an aside: You don't even need the `Reduce`, a simple `AAA // PiecewiseExpand // Simplify` does the job (even without the warning).

Comment: @sebhofer BTW, the output of `Simplify` isn't so perfect in version 8: what I get is `(0.00005 + dc == 0 && 160000. + 3.2*10^9 dc == 0) || dc >= 2.49955`. It's different in other version?

Comment: Yes, in version 9 `AAA // PiecewiseExpand // Simplify` yields `dc == -0.00005 || dc >= 2.49955` and `AAA // Rationalize // PiecewiseExpand // Simplify` gives `1 + 20000 dc == 0 || 20000 dc >= 49991`.

Comment: @sebhofer I've made a mistake 囧, see my edit.

Comment: Why don't you just integrate the `PiecewiseExpand//Simplify` solution in your answer? It was your idea anyway. And I think you can get rid of the obsolete part of the answer, nobody will mind.

Comment: @sebhofer OK, edited :)